# Push Notifications for enterprise windows phone 8.1

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, win-company-app

We have a request for an enterprise application on Windows Phone 8.1. We need to be able to publish the application on Hockey and use push notifications. What we have done until now:

- We have generated the build file
- We have bought an ‘Enterprise Mobile Code-Signing Certificate’ from Symantec so that we can sign and distribute the application.
- We have signed the application build with the certificate and successfully published on Hockey
- We have successfully downloaded and installed the application and the company profile from Hockey (application is working on the devices)

What we still need to do is to enable the push notifications on our application. What we have found regarding this is to use WNS, reserve an application name on dev center and use the generated PackageSID and Client Secret (from the dev center) to instantiate Push notifications. This works well but we than run into a CONFLICT: to use the ‘reserved application name’ we need to use the Publisher Name generated by the Dev Store, but to sign the application with the ‘Enterprise Mobile Code-Signing Certificate’ we need to use the Publisher Name from the certificate which is different from the one on the Dev Center. How can we overcome this? Is our approach correct in terms of publishing enterprise applications and/or use Push Notifications for enterprise applications?

We would like to know what are Microsoft recommendations in terms of using Push Notifications for enterprise applications.

Comment: In Dev center, they are providing Symantec id for the account. We need to use the same id and name of the person to the account belongs while getting the certificate.

Comment: If possible, try changing or reserving new app name in dev store and make it same as that of Symantec. This is the only way I can think of. Push notifications are same for all apps (enterprise or normal).

Comment: Is the requirement to use the PublisherID from the Dev Store actually a requirement for the WNS or is it being set because you're associating the app with the store? You can change the ID manually after it has been associated by diving into the `config.xml` and/or the `appsettings.config`.To Sign the app you'll need to use the certificate's "subject" (the one you're already correctly using) as the PublisherID and as far as I know there's no way around that.

Comment: You are right, there is no way around using subject as PublisherID, and that is why WNS will not work anymore. Microsoft was contacted and they don't support push notifications for WP8.1 LOB apps (this is an official answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for push notifications for WP8.1 LOB applications (this is an official answer from Microsoft).

Comment: We have to wait for windows 10 for a solution... nice work Microsoft :|